# CSS - Next row will not align underneath when 2 lines are present in the title

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

How do I adjust the CSS so that the next aligns directly underneath on the left side instead of under the next row ?

I've tried adjust the margin-bottom and padding-bottom and padding-top but it doesn't align correctly.

I understand the issue is with the title text 'The Little Paris Shop' is taking up two lines thus forcing the next image to over to the next item.

See screenshot: ('Radiant Angel' should be directly under 'The Little Paris Shop')

Screenshot

[image]

CSS

```
.for-sale-term a {
    font-size: 18px;
}
.for-sale-item2 {
    padding-top: 30px;
}
.col-xs-12.col-sm-6.col-md-3 {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center">
<div class="for-sale-item2">
    <div class="for-sale-image"><img src="example.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="for-sale-term"><a href="/little-paris-workshop">The Little Paris Bookshop</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center">
<div class="for-sale-item2">
    <div class="for-sale-image"><img src="example.jpg"></div>
    <div class="for-sale-term"><a href="/speaking-bones">Speaking In Bones</a></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center">
<div class="for-sale-item2">
    <div class="for-sale-image"><img src="example.jpg"></div>
    <div class="for-sale-term"><a href="/country">Up Country</a>    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center">
<div class="for-sale-item2">
    <div class="for-sale-image"><img src="example.jpg"></div>
    <div class="for-sale-term"><a href="/quest">The Quest</a></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center">
<div class="for-sale-item2">
<div class="for-sale-image"><img src="example.jpg"></div>
<div class="for-sale-term"><a href="/radiant-angel">Radiant Angel</a>  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last row is getting caught on the previous row because the text of "The Little Paris Bookshop" is on two lines. You can fix that by adding a class to clear it. For example:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center clearme">
<div class="for-sale-item2">
<div class="for-sale-image"><img src="/sites/default/files/example.jpg"></div>
<div class="for-sale-term"><a href="/radiant-angel">Radiant Angel</a>  </div>
</div>

.clearme {
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Tried this, and it's still not aligned underneath. Added in the class to this specific class and the `clear: both;`. No luck.

Comment: Works for me, http://www.bootply.com/3UTCWJsSjf. I forced the break in the example so you can test it.

Comment: Got it, added the clearme to the wrong class. (little parish shop instead of radiant angel) Is this the main way to handle these types of issues?